# jQuery - remove value from input attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, replace

My jQuery script adds products IDs to an input type="hidden" value="id1,id2,id3"

Script is working and adds the ids on checkbox change, but if I uncheck the box, id must be remove from that input.

Part of my code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="100" class="productid100">

<script>

 var productid = jQuery(".productid<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>").val();
 var defaultcombo = jQuery('.combodata').val();

 if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {

 jQuery('.combodata').attr("value", defaultcombo + productid+",");

 }else{

 var test = jQuery('#combo input:hidden[value=""]', productid+',').remove();
 console.log(test);

 }
</script>

<div id="combo">
<input type="hidden" class="hidden combodata" value="">
</div>
```

console.log()

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 100,
at Function.ga.error (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at ga.tokenize (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at ga.select (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at Function.ga [as find] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init.find (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at new m (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at m (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> ...
```

This code is inside a PHP foreach for each product show in page.

At final I just need to add product id on checkbox click and remove the specify id on uncheck.

Problem is here:

```
jQuery('#combo input:hidden[value=""]', productid+',').remove();
```

Comment: Try `jQuery('#combo input:not(:checked)').attr('value').remove();`

Comment: combo input is not the checkbox

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your question, look at @RoryMcCrossan answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is due to the syntax you're using with `remove()`. It's intended to remove elements from the DOM, not part of a string in the attribute of an element.

You can simplify the problem by building an array of the values of the hidden inputs related to the checked checkboxes, then calling `join()` on that array and setting it as the value of your hidden field, like this:

```js
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
  var values = $('.checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).next('.myclass').val();
  }).get();
  
  $('#output').val(values.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="id1" /> 
  <input type="hidden" value="100" class="myclass">
  id1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="id2" /> 
  <input type="hidden" value="200" class="myclass">
  id2
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="id3" /> 
  <input type="hidden" value="300" class="myclass">
  id3
</label>

<input type="text" id="output" />
```

Note that for this example the field is a text input so you can see the value being changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code, I tried and is working but it gets the value of the checkbox, I need to get the value of the input hidden, can this be made? `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" value="100" class="myclass">` The checkbox value I use it for product price and the other input is for product id.

Comment: Is the `hidden` input directly after the checkbox? It would help to see your actual HTML - if you could edit your question to include it

Comment: Yes, is exaclty after the checkbox, I am updating right now.

Comment: If it's directly after the checkbox it's fine. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Amazing, so simple and it taked me a lot of time. Really thank you for your time.